# Facebook Graph API - search doesn't return a list of groups

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm not sure if Facebook have made their API like this deliberately or if i'm missing something.

When using the Graph API explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Why does:

```
search?type=user&q=coffee
```

return a list of users who have the word coffee in their name

but

```
search?type=group&q=coffee
```

returns nothing:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

Is it impossible to search for a list of groups?

This works:

```
search?type=group&id=JavaScript.Programming
```

But what exactly is the point of a search when you already know the name or id of the group!?
I want to return a list of groups that have the word 'coffee' in them.
It seems totally illogical that you can search for users like that but not for groups.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get an Access token and select the permission user_group.

[image: screenshot]